# Spring in Action Chapter 4 testTrackCounter doesn't pass the test

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I learning Spring in action 4 chapter4,i can't pass the test!
The test error is

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expected :1
    Actual   :0
```

i debug the code, i realize counter size is zero
[debug img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozvpM.png)
but counter  in class TrackCounter size is not zero
[debug img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fgEy.png)

i can't understand why counter in test is{HashMap@2278} another is {HashMap@2294}
here is my code

CompactDisc:

```
package soundsystem;

public interface CompactDisc {
    void playTrack(int number);
}
```

BlankDisc：

```
package soundsystem;


import java.util.List;

public class BlankDisc implements CompactDisc {
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private List<String> tracks;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public void setTracks(List<String> tracks) {
        this.tracks = tracks;
    }


    @Override
    public void playTrack(int trackNumber) {
        System.out.println("-Track: " + tracks.get(trackNumber));
    }
}
```

```
package soundsystem;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Aspect
public class TrackCounter {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> trackCounts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    @Pointcut("execution(* soundsystem.CompactDisc.playTrack(int)) " +
            "&& args(trackNumber)")
    public void trackPlayed(int trackNumber) {
    }

    @Before(value = "trackPlayed(trackNumber)", argNames = "trackNumber")
    public void countTrack(int trackNumber) {
        int currentCount = getPlayCount(trackNumber);
        trackCounts.put(trackNumber, currentCount + 1);
    }

    public int getPlayCount(int trackNumber) {
        return trackCounts.getOrDefault(trackNumber, 0);
    }
}
```

TrackCountConfig ：

```
package soundsystem;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class TrackCountConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CompactDisc sgtPeppers() {
        BlankDisc cd = new BlankDisc();
        cd.setTitle("Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band");
        cd.setArtist("The Beatles");
        List<String> tracks = new ArrayList<String>();
        tracks.add("Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band");
        tracks.add("With A Little Help From My Friends");
        tracks.add("Lucy In The Sky With Diamonds");
        tracks.add("Getting Better");
        tracks.add("Fixing A Hole");
        tracks.add("She's Leaving Home");
        tracks.add("Being For The Benefit Of Mr. Kite!");
        tracks.add("Within You Without You");
        tracks.add("When I'm Sixty Four");
        tracks.add("Lovely Rita");
        tracks.add("Good Morning Good Morning");
        cd.setTracks(tracks);
        return cd;
    }

    @Bean
    public TrackCounter trackCounter() {
        return new TrackCounter();
    }
}
```

```
package soundsystem;


import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TrackCountConfig.class)
public class TrackCounterTest {
    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;
    @Autowired
    private TrackCounter counter;

    @Test
    public void testTrackCounter() {
        cd.playTrack(1);
        cd.playTrack(2);
        cd.playTrack(2);
        cd.playTrack(2);
        cd.playTrack(3);
        cd.playTrack(3);
        cd.playTrack(3);
        cd.playTrack(7);
        cd.playTrack(7);
        assertEquals(1, counter.getPlayCount(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not provide the source code for `CompactDisc` and `BlankDisc` but repeated the aspect instead. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around the WWW for the source code from that book because your question is missing two classes. I found them:

```java
package soundsystem;

public interface CompactDisc {
  void play();
  void playTrack(int track);
}
```

```java
package soundsystem;

import java.util.List;

public class BlankDisc implements CompactDisc {
  private String title;
  private String artist;
  private List<String> tracks;

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
  }

  public void setTracks(List<String> tracks) {
    this.tracks = tracks;
  }

  public void play() {
    System.out.println("Playing " + title + " by " + artist);
    for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
      playTrack(i);
    }
  }

  public void playTrack(int track) {
    System.out.println("-Track: " + tracks.get(track));
  }
}
```

With these two classes plus the ones you provided the test passes. If it does not pass for you, probably your implementation of `BlankDisc` is somehow different.

Comment: i update my code,`CompactDisc `and `BlankDisc ` look the same

Comment: Almost, but you removed method `play` because you do not use it in your test. Anyway, does your test work now? For me it still passes with your classes.

Comment: final,i pass the test when i use springboot Building my Environmen.i think the reason is my Development Environmen.thx you help me and tell my code,it work!

Comment: Then how about accepting (click the little checkmark to the left of the answer) and upvoting my answer? That would be thanks enough. :-)